# NDepend rule for checkin Async suffix

Tags: ndepend

I was wondering if there's a best way to perform such check.
I want to see all the methods that return a Task (or Task and don't have the "Async" suffix)

```
// <Name>Task type should be called with Async suffix</Name>
from m in Application.Methods
where m.ReturnType!= null && m.ReturnType.NameLike("Task") && 
!m.NameLike("Async")
select m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen `IMethod.IsAsync` property?    http://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.IMethod~IsAsync.html

```
from m in Application.Methods
where m.IsAsync
select m
```